# Converting simple foreach loop to stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose I have a simple class with method `eval()`. Is possible to convert this method to stream.reduce or something similar except for using `for` loop? `Operation` is interface with many possible implementations of method `execute` which compute different arithmetical operations.

```
public class Expression {
    private final List<Operation> operations;

    public Expression(List<Operation> operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    int eval() {
        int result = 0;
        for (Operation operation: operations) {
            result = operation.execute(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
int eval() {
    int[] r = {0};
    operations.stream()
        .forEach(op -> r[0] = op.execute(r[0]));
    return r[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**forEach**

Why not to try forEach() as the simplest and most common operation; it loops over the stream elements, calling the supplied function on each element.

```
public void eval() {    
    operations.stream().forEach(e -> e.execute());
         
}
```

This will effectively call the execute() on each element in the operations.

Also, a note to your current code is that result will have the latest result of operations execute, but not all.